# Adding additional javascript inside javascript-generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This seems like a simple question, but I don't know the correct syntax to make it work.

I have this code that's used by DataTables to generate a table:

```
'<td>'+d.expirationDate+'</td>'+
'<td>'+d.dateReceived+'</td>'+
```

I'd like to add a qualifier onto this that if the date field is not set, to display nothing instead of the word `null`.

So I tried this:

```
'<td class="dropInfo">'+
  if (d.debitExpDate !== 'null') {
   d.expirationDate
  } 
+'</td>'+
```

but I get an error.  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

What's the correct syntax for this?

Comment: You would have to create the string depending on a condition. Check the condition first then create the string according to the condition result. If you do this often, look into using a formatting library such as Handlebars.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a logical or ||

```
'<td>'+d.expirationDate+'</td>'+
'<td>' + (d.dateReceived || '') + '</td>'
```

|| evalutes the first thing on the left. If the left is "truthy" then it uses that value otherwise it uses the second thing.

Since null is not a truthy value in this case it will choose the empty string.

Comment: sweet - i love it.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Several solutions are available.

Solution1: One line synthaxe, as pointed out by @Tom DDD (see his post)

```
'<td>'+d.expirationDate+'</td>'+
'<td>' + (d.dateReceived || '') + '</td>'+
```

Solution2 : Split the generation of your js with **;** and concacenate with **+=**

```
var js = '<td class="dropInfo">';
  if (d.debitExpDate !== 'null') {
   js +=d.expirationDate
  } 
js+='</td>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are just fine, but there is another common option:

`'<td>'+(d.expirationDate===null ? '' : d.expirationDate)+'</td>'`

The advantage here is that more complex conditions can also be used. for example:

`'<td>'+(d.expirationDate>Date.now() ? '' : d.expirationDate)+'</td>'`

Comment: really nice - the syntax is correct, and the additional `Date.now` is actually something I wanted to use eventually :)

Comment: @JohnWu - Feel free to change your "correct answer" selection ;-)